# firebase function for stripe webhook does not work with async-await

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am using the excellent [stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/build#key-considerations) to build a webhook to respond to a stripe successful payment. The code works fine however as soon as I introduced async-await, I get a 500 Internal server error.

I am testing the firebase onRequest webhook function through the `send test webhook` on the stripe website.
My code lives [here](https://github.com/ajitgoel/VideoAudioTranscription-Firebase/blob/master/functions/src/index.ts)

What am I missing?

**firebase function with async-await does not work:**

```
exports.stripeEvents = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => 
{
  try
  {    
    let stripesignature = request.headers['stripe-signature'] as string;
    let stripeevent:Stripe.Event= stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.rawBody.toString('utf8'), stripesignature, config.stripewebhooksecretkey);

    if(stripeevent.type === 'payment_intent.succeeded')
    {
      let payment_intent1 = stripeevent.data.object as Stripe.PaymentIntent;
      let datafirstelement=null;
      if(payment_intent1?.charges?.data && payment_intent1?.charges?.data.length>0)
      {
        datafirstelement=payment_intent1?.charges?.data[0];
      }        
      let userid='someuserid';
      let documentreference=config.db.collection('users').doc(userid);
      await documentreference.update({payments: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(datafirstelement)}); 
      response.status(200).send({'result':true});
    }
  }
  catch(error)
  {
    //log error into sentry
    throw error;
  }
});
```

**firebase function without async-await, works:**

```
exports.stripeEvents = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => 
{
  try
  {    
    let stripesignature = request.headers['stripe-signature'] as string;
    let stripeevent:Stripe.Event= stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.rawBody.toString('utf8'), stripesignature, config.stripewebhooksecretkey);

    if(stripeevent.type === 'payment_intent.succeeded')
    {
      let payment_intent1 = stripeevent.data.object as Stripe.PaymentIntent;
      let datafirstelement=null;
      if(payment_intent1?.charges?.data && payment_intent1?.charges?.data.length>0)
      {
        datafirstelement=payment_intent1?.charges?.data[0];
      }        
      let userid='someuserid';
      let documentreference=config.db.collection('users').doc(userid);
      //await documentreference.update({payments: //admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(datafirstelement)}); 
      response.status(200).send({'result':true});
    }
  }
  catch(error)
  {
    //log error into sentry
    throw error;
  }
});
```

**update 1:** I am testing the firebase onRequest webhook function through the `send test webhook` on the stripe website.

**successful stripe payments when not using async-await, internal server error when using async-await:**

[image]

**webhook success logs when not using async-await(and no logs when using async-await):**

[image]

**update 2: firebase function log:**

```
stripeEvents
Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.
    at Object.validateResourcePath (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/path.js:403:15)
    at CollectionReference.doc (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1988:20)
    at exports.stripeEvents.functions.https.onRequest (/workspace/lib/index.js:115:85)
    at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:51:16)
    at process.nextTick (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:99:17)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

**update 3: firebase function log:**
I changed line `await documentreference.update({payments: //admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(datafirstelement)});` to `await documentreference.set({payments: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(datafirstelement)}, {merge:true});` and the application still throws the following errors. The code lives [here](https://github.com/ajitgoel/VideoAudioTranscription-Firebase/blob/master/functions/src/index.ts).

```
12:02:30.464 AM
stripeEvents
Function execution started 
12:02:54.174 AM
stripeEvents
Function execution started 
12:02:54.901 AM
stripeEvents
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason: 
12:02:54.905 AM
stripeEvents
Function execution took 732 ms, finished with status: 'crash' 
12:03:30.467 AM
stripeEvents
Function execution took 60004 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
```

Comment: What does your functions log say the problem is?  Please edit the question to include the full error and what line it refers to.

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson for your input, I have added more details in the question. No errors are being logged in my logging system, stripe logs shows a 500 internal server error when it tries to contact firebase onRequest function.

Comment: For your `catch` block, can you return the response error like 
`console.log(error)`
`response.status(500).send({err: `${err}`})`  you might be able to capture the error and the error most likely is thrown by `documentreference.update()` call

Comment: I'm referring to your cloud functions log, not stripe.  If your javascript is throwing an error, the log should have details.

Comment: Thank you @wsw, I am logging the error into sentry but I do not see any error in sentry. Like you suggested(and I found in the firebase function logs), it is an error related to the documentreference.update() call. I will investigate.

Comment: Can you share the **entire** code of your CloudFunction and in particular how you declare `config`. Are you 100% sure that in the code you run, `userid` has a valid value (I.e. it is a non-empty string)?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, you are right, I need to test it from the web application instead of the "send test webhook" on the stripe website.

Comment: Do you confirm that it works when you pass a valid value for `userid`?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, you are right, the system is losing the userid somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments above and from the error you get (`Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.`), it seems that the value you pass to the `doc()` method while testing your Cloud Function is an empty string.

You need to mock data in your test in order to pass a correct value to the `doc()` method.

---

Note that I’m not sure that testing it "from the web application" (as you mention in the comments above) will change something, since the stripe Webhook has nothing to do with your web application (the Stripe backend calls your backend, i.e. your Cloud Function). You may send the userId as payment metadata to Stripe and (1) add it as query string parameter to the URL called by the webhook and (2) parse and use this value in your Cloud Function.

---

Note also that the difference between your "async version" that does not work and you "non async version" that works is not about async/await but is just that you comment out the line that generates the error.